# Synchronize to Form Thread - without usinig Form

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

using Windows Forms it is possible to synchronize incoming data (like from events) which runs on another thread as that one which has created the form. However it is not allowed to update the form directly, therefore InvokeRequired and Invoke are used. Works great for me.

Now I want to move the logic part of my application (contains serial, networking, ... hence the threads) into a library. Also I want to have the synchronization in there, so there is no need to take care about that externally.

For now I create and pass a dummy form to my library, which is ugly, but works. At least some kind of. .Net Core has no Windows Forms. (3.0 has, but Windows only).

Even after reflecting the Form class I was not able to reproduce the synchronization process, so I could add it to my classes.

Does anyone know how to archive the same behaviour without Windows.Forms?

*I use .Net Framework 2.0 and VB.Net, but C# examples are welcome as well*

Comment: Why are you using .NET Framework 2.0? Why can't you at least bring it up to 3.5? (Note that 3.5 uses the 2.0 CLR, so 99% of the time you can safely upgrade)

Comment: I recommend you search online for the "producer-consumer problem" as it's a common problem in multi-threaded programming.

Comment: @Dai: I know that I could upgrade. But I had problems in the past with backward compatibility and Mono. Also I don't use the new features, so there is no need to do it. Ok, for such a term I haven't searched yet.

Comment: [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext) Class.